# WebRequest and Stream Reading fail on an atom feed url

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

```
    Stream FeedReader(string url_)
    {
        var url = url_;

        var USER = "user";
        var PASS = "password";


        var encoded = TextToBase64(USER + ":" + PASS);

        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(USER, PASS);
        myWebRequest.Credentials = netCred;            

        //WebResponse response = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var stream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        return stream;
    }
```

I am using the above source code to get the atom feed stream which is then passed in the following function

```
    public static List<Item> ParseAtom2(Stream stream)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);//("atom.xml");
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

        var entries = doc.Root
             .Elements(ns + "entry")
             .Select(item => new Item
             {
                 FeedType = FeedType.Atom,
                 Content = (string)item.Element(ns + "content"),
                 Link = (string)item.Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href"),
                 PublishDate = (DateTime)item.Element(ns + "published"),
                 Title = (string)item.Element(ns + "title")
             });
        return entries.ToList();
    }
```

I however get an error stating that the stream in unreadable, I would like to know what might have been the problem. 
The atom feed url looks like this http://server.com/posts.atom.xml/

Comment: Its a good idea to include the error type and the exact error message. Also are you really using c# 2.0 - 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

You return RequestStream it contains data that would be sent to server so you can't read anything from it, try using `myWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()`

Comment: Thanks, I have got an exception of timeout in GetResponse();

Comment: It seems that ther is something wrong with your server. Does  http://server.com/posts.atom.xml/ open OK in browser?